# Spring Data Elasticsearch cusom repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my Spring Boot application I'm trying to implement a fuzzy search via Elasticsearch.

This is my ES config:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.elasticsearch")
public class ElasticsearchTestConfig {
}
```

I have a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ESDecisionRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ESDecision, String>, ESDecisionRepositoryCustom {
}
```

In order to be able to do a fuzzy search I have created a custom repository:

```
public interface ESDecisionRepositoryCustom {

    public List<ESDecision> findFuzzyBySearchTerm(String searchTerm);

}
```

and provided a custom implementation:

```
@Repository
public class ESDecisionRepositoryCustomImpl implements ESDecisionRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    protected ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<ESDecision> findFuzzyBySearchTerm(String searchTerm) {
        Criteria c = new Criteria("name").fuzzy(searchTerm);
        return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(new CriteriaQuery(c), ESDecision.class);
    }

}
```

Right now during startup my application fails with a following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ESDecisionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property searchTerm found for type ESDecision!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property searchTerm found for type ESDecision!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.<init>(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory$ElasticsearchQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you have a property `searchTerm` in your `ESDecision` entity class?

Comment: No, I don't have such property

Comment: Try changing your custom repo implementation name to  `ESDecisionRepositoryImpl `. There is a naming convention for custom repository implementation and you need to follow it to make it work. Check out the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)

Comment: Yes, it was the mistake. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your custom repository implementation class name from `ESDecisionRepositoryCustomImpl` to `ESDecisionRepositoryImpl`.

From the docs

> The most important bit for the class to be found is the Impl postfix of the name on it compared to the core repository interface (see below).

There is a naming convention that has to be followed to make the custom repository implementation work. Check out the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)

Try this:

```
@Repository
public class ESDecisionRepositoryCustomImpl implements ESDecisionRepositoryCustom {

     @Autowired
     protected ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

     @Override
     public List<ESDecision> findFuzzyBySearchTerm(String searchTerm) {
         Criteria c = new Criteria("name").fuzzy(searchTerm);
         return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(new CriteriaQuery(c), ESDecision.class);
     }

}
```

Hope this helps.